# Why does Dropwizard deserialization not find an appender when I simply extend the default logger?

Tags: java, jackson, dropwizard

I have a YML file for configuration that includes the dropwizard logging, like so:

```
logging:
  level: WARN
  loggers:
    com.<company>.<product>: INFO
  appenders:
    - type: console
(etc)
```

I have a simple class to read the YAML file and a class like:

```
public class MyConfiguration {

    private CommonLoggingFactory loggingFactory;

    public MyConfiguration() {

    }

    public MyConfiguration(CommonLoggingFactory loggingFactory) {
        this.loggingFactory = loggingFactory;
    }

    @JsonProperty("logging")
    public CommonLoggingFactory getLoggingFactory() {
        return loggingFactory;
    }

    @JsonProperty("logging")
    public void setLoggingFactory(CommonLoggingFactory loggingFactory) {
        this.loggingFactory = loggingFactory;
    }
}
```

with my new logging factory class being...

```
@JsonTypeName("logging")
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "type", defaultImpl = CommonLoggingFactory.class)
public class CommonLoggingFactory extends DefaultLoggingFactory {

    //TODO Any changes
}
```

Where DefaultLoggingFactory is io.dropwizard.logging.DefaultLoggingFactory

So, it appears that the deserializer (jackson) can find the DefaultLoggingFactory, but then doesn't continue to follow the chain to appenders.

```
Could not resolve type id 'console' as a subtype of `io.dropwizard.logging.AppenderFactory<ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent>`: known type ids = [] (for POJO property 'appenders')
 at [Source: (File); line: 80, column: 1] (through reference chain: com.<my company>.MyConfiguration["logging"]->com.<mycompany>.CommonLoggingFactory["appenders"]->java.util.ArrayList[0])
```

I would have thought that it would be automatically picked up. I've tried a few things like [How to configure Jackson to deserialize named types with default typing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38380412/how-to-configure-jackson-to-deserialize-named-types-with-default-typing/38417267#38417267) by telling the object mapper to map "console" to ConsoleAppenderFactory.class, but no joy.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Your `MyConfiguration` class needs to extend the `io.dropwizard.Configuration`

Comment: @dshelya -- A good thought, but that did not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason I had to add the following setup method

```
private void doSetup() {
   final Map<String, Class<?>> typesByName = new HashMap<String,Class<>>();
   typesByName.put("console", ConsoleAppenderFactory.class);
   SimpleModule namedTypesModule = new SimpleModule("my-named-types-module");
   Set<Class<?>> appenderFactoryClasses = new HashSet<>();
   appenderFactoryClasses.add(ConsoleAppenderFactory.class);
   appenderFactoryClasses.add(FileAppenderFactory.class);
   //etc
   namedTypesModule.registerSubtypes(appenderFactoryClasses);
   namedTypesModule.addDeserializer(Object.class, 
     new JacksonDeserializerOfNamedTypes(typesByName, 
        JsonTypeInfo.Id.Name.getPropertyName()));
   //After doing the above the read then worked ...
   ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new YAMLFactory());
   mapper.readValue(file, *ExpectedClass*.class);
   ...
}
```

Comment: Also worth checking https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542066/dropwizard-failed-to-parse-configuration-at-logging-appenders